# is it possible to do subquery inside GROUP BY?

Tags: php, sql, group-by, subquery

my problem analogy is like this:

```
table: place
id   title            branch
===============================
1    pizza store      california
2    pizza store      manhattan
3    coffee shop      california
4    pizza store      texas
5    cookie store     new york

table: rating
id    place_id     rating
================================
1     1            3.5
2     2            5.0
3     2            4.2
4     2            5.0
5     5            4.0
```

i use query:

```
 SELECT F.id AS id, F.title AS title, G.rating 
 FROM place F 
 JOIN rating G ON F.id = G.place_id 
 GROUP BY F.title
```

the display will be :

```
id   title          rating
===========================
1    pizza store    3.5
3    coffee shop    -
5    cookie store   4.0
```

what i want is to sort title that has rating with the maximum one, in this case i want it to display pizza store with rating 5 and id 2. Is it possible to insert some subquery inside GROUP BY ?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The query you have makes no sense.  You can't select id and rating but only group by title.

Comment: FYI, this is just analogy of my problem dude

Comment: Yes, analogy of MySQL's problem :)

Comment: @dbaseman: just to clarify, mySQL considers this to be valid SQL syntax and will use arbitrary values for the result. I'd say the cause of the problem in this case is mySQL.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
SELECT F.id , F.title, s.Maxrating 
FROM place F 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id,Max(rating) as MaxRating FROM rating  GROUP BY place_id ) s 
ON s.id = F.id
```

Comment: thx diEcho for this approach! i believe this is the solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT F.id AS id, F.title AS title, max(G.rating)
FROM place F, rating G
where F.id = G.place_id(+)
group by f.id, f.title
```

Comment: Iam using outer Join.if any querie u can refer http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php

Comment: thx user1127214, your approach is similar to diEcho which i believe is the solution to my problem! :)